# Load new content page in the current web

Tags: jquery, ajax, loading

How can I with jQuery load the content of a new page ?

Here my HTML:

```
  <ul>
    <li><a href="../index.php" class="tab">page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.ca" class="tab">page 2</a></li>
  </ul>
<div id="response"></div>
```

Here my jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.tab").click(function(){
            $("#response").html(load($(this).attr('href')));
    });
});
</script>
```

Problem: it redirect to the page.

I want the first url stay the same.

How can I do that please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it directly using `jQuery.load` as well (along with @Maulik Anands note on keeping the link click event from executing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('a.tab').click(function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $('#response').load($(this).attr('href'));
       return false;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.tab").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#response").html(load($(this).attr('href')));
    });
});
</script>
```

You can Prevent Postback this way Or you can also `return false`;